# JSR 356 WebSocket (Java WebSocket 1.0) support is not available when running on Java 6

Tags: java, tomcat, struts2, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to run my first struts "Hello World" program on Eclipse Kepler (4.3) on Tomcat 7. JRE is jrockit-jre1.6.0_45-R28.2.7.
And I got 404 error. Here is the error on console

```
 2014/11/12 18:46:38 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
    情報: サービス Catalina を起動します
    2014/11/12 18:46:38 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
    情報: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.53
    2014/11/12 18:46:38 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci onStartup
    情報: JSR 356 WebSocket (Java WebSocket 1.0) support is not available when running on Java 6. To suppress this message, run Tomcat on Java 7, remove the WebSocket JARs from $CATALINA_HOME/lib or add the WebSocketJARs to the tomcat.util.scan.DefaultJarScanner.jarsToSkip property in $CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties. Note that the deprecated Tomcat 7 WebSocket API will be available. 
    2014/11/12 18:46:39 com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider info
    情報: Parsing configuration file [struts-default.xml]
    2014/11/12 18:46:39 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
    致命的: フィルタ struts2 の起動中の例外です
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:211)
        at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:102)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:234)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:445)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:489)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4809)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5485)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    2014/11/12 18:46:39 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
    致命的: Error filterStart
    2014/11/12 18:46:39 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
    致命的: 以前のエラーのためにコンテキストの起動が失敗しました [/StrutsHelloWord]
    2014/11/12 18:46:39 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    情報: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    2014/11/12 18:46:39 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    情報: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    2014/11/12 18:46:39 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    情報: Server startup in 1738 ms
```

I would be very appreciate if you could tell me the cause of this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite the bunch of Hiragana in your stacktrace, luckily errors and exceptions are still recognizable. This:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils

is thrown because you are missing `commons-lang3-3.x.jar` in your classpath.

[Download it](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.3.2), include it in your package, enjoy.

This instead

> 情報: JSR 356 WebSocket (Java WebSocket 1.0) support is not available when running on Java 6. To suppress this message, run Tomcat on Java 7, remove the WebSocket JARs from $CATALINA_HOME/lib or add the WebSocketJARs to the tomcat.util.scan.DefaultJarScanner.jarsToSkip property in $CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties. Note that the deprecated Tomcat 7 WebSocket API will be available.

is self-explanatory: use Java 7 because JSR 356 [seems to target that](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=356).